# A Partial fractions question .

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How to rewrite this expression $$\frac{1}{\prod_{k=0}^{k=m}(z+k)} \;\; \text{to the form} \;\; \sum_{k=0}^{k=m}(\frac{\alpha _{k}}{z+k}) \; \text{?}$$

Comment: The usual way --- clear fractions, then evaluate at $z=0$, at $z=-1$, $z=-2$, and so on. Each evaluation gets you another $a_k$.

Comment: First think if m is small (1 or 2)

Comment: Make the cross product : on the lhs, you have $1$. Simplify the rhs for each fraction and do what Gerry Myerson said. For each $z=-j$, you get $a_j$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
a_j
&= \lim_{z \to -j} \frac{(z + j)}{\prod\limits_{k=0}^m(z+k)} \\
&= \frac{1}{(m-j)(m-1 - j) \cdots (1)(-1)(-2)\cdots (-j)} \\
&= \frac{1}{(m-j)!j! (-1)^j} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^j}{j! (m-j)!} \\
\end{align*}